# How to build a lazy sequence of perfect number in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I tried to find a list of perfect number in this way:

```
(defn classify [num] 
  (let [factors (->> (range 1 (inc num))
                     (filter #(zero? (rem num %))))
        sum (reduce + factors)
        aliquot-sum (- sum num)]
    (cond
      (= aliquot-sum num) :perfect
      (> aliquot-sum num) :abundant
      (< aliquot-sum num) :deficient)))

(defn is-p [n] 
  (= :perfect (classify n)))

(defn list-perfect [n]
  (filter is-p (range 1 (inc n))))
```

Question:

1. How to build a lazy sequence of perfect numbers, so that I can use `(take n ...)` to easily get a list.
2. Is this code idiomatic and efficient? Any improvement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i'd rename `is-p` to `perfect?`

Comment: @cfrick Yes, I should have done that! Thank you.

Comment: regarding efficiency: your method is incredibly slow for large numbers. I've added an answer that reduces it from an O(n) to O(sqrt n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list-perfect` is already lazy due to your usage of [filter](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/filter):

> (filter pred coll)
>
> Returns a lazy sequence of the items in coll for which
> (pred item) returns true. pred must be free of side-effects.

Whether code is idiomatic or not might be a matter of opinion (and hence off-topic), but it looks good enough from my perspective.

Comment: Thank you for the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm is very inefficient, it's `O(n)`.

For a quick win, you can immediately reduce the range by a half, as you won't ever have factors that are greater than the number you're testing divided by 2.

So change it to:

```
(defn classify [num] 
  (let [factors (->> (range 1 (max 2 (inc (quot num 2))))
  ;; ...
```

**However...** you can change it to `O(sqrt n)` which is magnitudes faster. See my timings below.

The real efficiency is noticing that factors are in pairs of `[x (quot num x)]` and then only check the first `(sqrt num)` (or slightly over):

```
(defn perfect? [n]
  (let [r (range 2 (+ 2 (int (Math/sqrt n))))
        s (set (mapcat #(if (zero? (rem n %))
                          [% (quot n %)])
                       r))
        t (reduce + 1 s)]
    (= n t)))
```

I've split it into separate calculations so you can verify each stage.

The range can be reduced from 2..((sqrt n) + 2), and initialise the reduction with 1 (which is always a factor).

This changes the problem from an O(n) to O(sqrt n), so if you're checking large numbers, makes a vast difference.

As an illustration here are some times on larger values for n on my MBP:

```
         n            "n/2"      "sqrt n"
      33550336       1,172.5ms     2.85ms
    8589869056     274,346.6ms    16.76ms
  137438691328     didn't time    44.27ms
```

so using root version was 16,369 times faster for the 6th perfect number. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_perfect_numbers for more details.

**EDIT:**

Why (int (root n)) + 2? And why `[x (quot n x)]?

When you work out the factors of a number n, then if you find one (say, `a`), then `n/a` is also a factor (call it `b`) because `n = a * b`

e.g. looking at 28, the first relevant factor is 2, and clearly 28/2 = 14 is also a factor. So you don't need to check 14, you already know it's a factor from the fact that 2 is.

as we're incrementally checking numbers from 2 upwards, we're incidentally finding the higher numbers coming down:

```
2 is a factor, 28 / 2 = 14 -> [a, b] = [2, 14]
4 is a factor, 28 / 4 = 7  -> [a, b] = [4,  7]
7 is a factor, 28 / 7 = 4  -> [a, b] = [7,  4] - wait a minute...
```

The `[a,b]` pairs here are the `[% (quot n %)]` in the mapcat function, e.g. when the range is currently iterating the value `2`, then `%` is `2` inside the fuction, and so `(quot n %)` is `(quot 28 2)` which is 14, thus `[% (quot n %)]` is simply the vector `[2 14]`, which then gets added to the set after being flattened to `2` and `14` as values. Later, when the range value is `4`, then `[% (quot n %)]` is `[4 (quot 28 4)]` which is `[4 7]`, and again is flattened by mapcat as the numbers `4` and `7`.

So we add each pair of numbers (flattened via mapcat) to our set, include the number 1, and end up with `#{1  2 14  4 7}`, which are the factors of 28. (Actually, I don't put 1 in the set as I don't need to, instead I start the summing reduction at 1, which is same effect).

But at what point do they turn around? i.e. when do we know that `[7,4]` will already have been included in the set as `[4,7]`?

clearly it's when `a` > `b`, because in finding the lowest numbers we always find the highest number with it, so we can finish checking at this point.

but what is this point? it's simple, if a perfect number were a square number, then a and b would be equal, i.e. a*a = n, so a = sqrt(n).

Thus the highest value of `a` we need to check is the whole number that is larger than the root of `n`.

e.g. for 28, sqrt(28) = 5.292, so we have to check 6 to be sure that we've included the lowest number possible that could be a factor that has a paired factor.

so we need (int (sqrt n)) + 1.

I always do this in case the root calculation is 1.9999999999... and rounds wrong way, so adding 1 more ensures you eliminate any rounding errors.

but in a range, if you want to include that number you have to add 1 more to it (range drops the high number, (range 6) = (0 1 2 3 4 5)), hence why it adds 2 to the value: 1 for the range, 1 to ensure it's above the rounded down root.

Although, after saying this, I've tested perfect numbers up to 2305843008139952128 and it works with +1 instead of +2, not that it's a massive saving. Probably because non of the perfect numbers are close to perfect squares in ones I checked, so there's no rounding error in `(int (sqrt n))`.

If you're interested in perfect numbers, I'd recommend reading http://britton.disted.camosun.bc.ca/perfect_number/lesson1.html

Comment: Wow, your algorithm runs faster. (1) I'm not good at mathematics, how do you pick the number for `slightly over (sqrt num)`? you picked `(+ 2 (Math/sqrt num))`. Will it be correct if I use `(+ 1 (Math/sqrt num))`? (2) The line `s (set (mapcat #(if (zero? (rem n %)) [(quot n %) %]) r))` is not straight forward to a beginner like me. I guess you mean to collect the quotients. But I can't figure out how you did it. Could you please add a little bit explaination? Thank you.

Comment: Read http://britton.disted.camosun.bc.ca/perfect_number/lesson1.html - i'll add some explanation to my answer rather than in a comment.

Comment: the quick answers: +2 is because range needs an extra 1 (it drops the last number in range) and +1 to ensure there are no computer rounding errors in calculating (sqrt n), e.g. if it calculated 1.999999999999 as root of 4, then we'd be short by 1 after taking (int 1.999999). the pairs of [x (quot n x)] are explained in answer. it's simple if you write the factors out.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for your detailed explanation. You've been so kind of a beginner, and your explanation reminds me of some fine text book. I like your thought from O(n), to  a quick win (O(n/2)), to O(sqrt(n)). I understand almost all of your thought, except the `[(quot n %) %]` part -- the syntax. I know this vector collects all the quotients, but I don't undersand the usage for the second `%`. I know I've been asking too many questions. If you can, please point me any hint to search it in the documentation. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help Nick. The `[(quot n %) %]` is easy. It's adding `[2 14]`, `[4 7]` to the set (as per my examples), but! the mapcat turns them into `2 14` and `4 7` by flattening the vectors into simple numbers. I'll expand the src because that is part of the anonymous function that mapcat is calling for each item in the range.

Comment: I've added more to my answer explaining why I'm using the vector to add to the set.

Comment: Ah! It's the `[a b]` pair! Now I understand both the idea and the code. Thank you very much!